# Is it possible to use multiple delmiter when we write to csv with python?

Tags: python, csv, format, delimiter

I have a txt file, which one i want do read to csv.

```js
output=csv.writer(resultcsv, delimiter=';',quotechar = '"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, encoding='latin-1')
```

It is correct for me, when i want this :

```js
"1";
"2";
"3";
```

But in some row, i see this :

```js
"1";
"2
3
"
"";
```

And this result something bad when i open it in excel.

How can I fix this, to take these values for a new line and not continue under the value "2" in the same cell?

My full code:

```js
import urllib2
import unicodecsv as csv
import os
import sys
import io
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import MySQLdb

 
filename=r'output.csv'

resultcsv=open(filename,"wb")
output=csv.writer(resultcsv, delimiter=';',quotechar = '"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, encoding='latin-1')
 
f = open('1234.txt', 'r')
x = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(x, 'lxml')

#i determine here the "datatable"

output.writerows(datatable)

resultcsv.close()
```

Comment: show `resultcsv` fragment

Comment: What is the type of `resultcsv` (numpy array,...?)? From your code, it is not possible to find out what your starting point is?

Comment: resultcsv is in csv format, oke, i update my quest. with the full code. #edited

Comment: You might have a \n accompanying your data.